# Compiler introducing extra interface requirements when using functions returning dependent pairs

Tags: idris, theorem-proving

This is rather complicated. Sorry I could'n make the example simpler. I'm trying to formalize a theory and interfaces A and B represent my axioms. `X` and `Y` are some objects in the theory, `mkY` creates a `Y` from two `X`s and `PropA`, `PropY` and `PropYY` are some statements about these objects:

```
interface A a where
    PropA : a -> Type

interface B where
    X : Type
    Y : Type
    PropY : Y -> Type
    mkY : A X => (x, y : X) -> (z : Y ** PropY z)
    PropYY : Y -> Type
    mkPropY : A X => {x : X} -> {y : Y} -> PropA x -> PropY y -> PropYY y

lemma1 : (B, A X) => (x, y : X) -> PropA x -> (z : Y ** PropYY z)
lemma1 x y prop_a =
    let (z ** propZ) = mkY x y in
    (z ** mkPropY prop_a propZ)
```

Unfortunately rather obvious `lemma1` does not compile:

```
When checking right hand side of Example.case block in lemma1 at /home/sven/code/idris/geometry/src/Euclid/Example.idr:17:9-20 with expected type
        (z1 : Y ** PropYY z1)

When checking an application of function Example.mkPropY:
        Type mismatch between
                PropA x1 (Type of prop_a)
        and
                PropA x (Expected type)
```

It seems to me Idris refuses to unify requirement `A X` from the function header with that introduced by `mkY` function. When I replace `mkPropY prop_a propZ` with a hole and ask for its type, I get this:

```
constraint : B
  z : Y
  propZ : PropY z
  x : X
  y : X
  constraint1 : A X
  prop_a : PropA x
  constraint2 : A X
--------------------------------------
whatIsIt : PropYY z
```

Here `constraint1` and `constraint2` are the same, and yet there's two of them, which seems to be the root cause of the problem. So why does Idris introduce this additional constraint and how do I make it work?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why Idris thinks with `mkY` there could be another constraint in play (as by the looks of it nothing in the hole is constrained by it, even with `:set showimplicits`). Maybe someone else can explain why, but for now it usually helps to make constraints explicit:

```
lemma1 : (B, a_const : A X) => (x, y : X) -> PropA x -> (z : Y ** PropYY z)
lemma1 @{a_const} x y prop_a =
    let (z ** propZ) = mkY @{a_const} x y in
    (z ** mkPropY prop_a propZ)
```

(Maybe rewriting `B` as `interface B x y where; …` would help, so the scope over `X` and `Y` is clearer, but I didn't try this.)

Comment: Indeed, it helps. Thank you very much. As for parametrizing the interface `B`, having multiparameter interfaces create different problems, especially if some parameters are unimportant for the lemma in question. When the same interface is required by a number of functions inside a proof, Idris also tends to differentiate these constraints and prohibits use of functions because you haven't specified an exact parameter (which you don;t want to specify beacuse it should not matter). However, maybe the same technique can mittigate these problems as well. Thanks a lot anyway!